# I am writing a mini library website with borrow and return post method using node js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, node.js-fs

I am trying to finish a homepage for a mini library website with these requirements.

1. a left indented checkboxed form with title of the available books; has a button called borrow
2. a right indented checkboxed form with title of the borrowed books; has a button called return
3. when a checkbox is clicked and button is pressed, the books will be updated as per request; when borrowed it will disappear from the left side and appear on the right side and vice versa for returned books.

I tried creating .hbs file with necessary helps and escape characters. I also created a get method for the /home page and a post method for the /return and /borrow functions. I was expecting the borrow and return function to update the books and their status, however, the page only refreshes not update the "available" property of the books.

```
{{> Heading}}

<div class="container">
  <div class="left-container">
    <h2>Available Books</h2>
    <form action="/borrow" method="POST">
      {{#each availableBooks}}
        {{#if available}}
          <div class="book">
            <input type="checkbox" name="books[]" value="{{title}}">
            <span>{{title}}</span>
          </div>
        {{/if}}
      {{/each}}
      <button type="submit" name="action" value="borrow" id="borrowButton" disabled>Borrow</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="right-container">
    <h2>Borrowed Books</h2>
    <form action="/return" method="POST">
      {{#each borrowedBooks}}
        {{#unless available}}
          <div class="book">
            <input type="checkbox" name="books[]" value="{{title}}">
            <span>{{title}}</span>
          </div>
        {{/unless}}
      {{/each}}
      <button type="submit" name="action" value="return" id="returnButton" disabled>Return</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  // Enable borrow button when at least one checkbox is selected in the left container
  const borrowButton = document.getElementById('borrowButton');
  const leftContainerCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.left-container input[type="checkbox"]');

  leftContainerCheckboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
      const anyChecked = Array.from(leftContainerCheckboxes).some((checkbox) => checkbox.checked);
      borrowButton.disabled = !anyChecked;
    });
  });

  // Enable return button when at least one checkbox is selected in the right container
  const returnButton = document.getElementById('returnButton');
  const rightContainerCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.right-container input[type="checkbox"]');

  rightContainerCheckboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
      returnButton.disabled = !Array.from(rightContainerCheckboxes).some((checkbox) => checkbox.checked);
    });
  });
</script>
```

```
const HTTP_PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const express = require("express");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));



app.use(session({
  secret: 'your-secret-key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

function onHttpStart() {
  console.log("Express http server listening on: " + HTTP_PORT);
}

let booksData = [];

fs.readFile('books.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  booksData = JSON.parse(data);
  
});



app.engine(".hbs", exphbs.engine({
  extname: ".hbs",
  defaultLayout: false,
  layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, "/views")
}));

app.set("view engine", ".hbs");

// Middleware to check session authentication
function authenticateSession(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.username) {
    next(); // User is authenticated, continue to the next middleware
  } else {
    res.redirect('/LandingPage'); // User is not authenticated, redirect to LandingPage
  }
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('Landing Page', { layout: false });
});

app.get("/LandingPage", function(req, res) {
  res.render('Landing Page', { layout: false });
});

app.get("/SignIn", function(req, res) {
  res.render('Sign In', { heading: 'uLibrary', layout: false });
});

app.post('/signin', express.urlencoded({ extended: false }), (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  // Read the users.json file
  fs.readFile('./users.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }

    const users = JSON.parse(data);

    // Check if the entered username exists in the users.json file
    if (!users.hasOwnProperty(username)) {
      //return res.render('Sign In', {
       // error: 'Not a registered username',
       // layout: false
      //});
      return res.redirect('/LandingPage');
    }

    // Check if the entered password matches the stored password for the username
    if (users[username] !== password) {
      //return res.render('Sign In', {
       // error: 'Invalid password',
       // layout: false
      //});
      return res.redirect('/LandingPage');
    }

    // Successful sign in, set username in session
    req.session.username = username;

    // Redirect to the Home Webpage
    res.redirect('/home');
  });
});

app.get('/home', authenticateSession, (req, res) => {
  const username = req.session.username;
  const availableBooks = booksData.filter((book) => book.available);
  const borrowedBooks = booksData.filter((book) => !book.available);
  res.render('Home', { 
    heading: 'Home',
    availableBooks: availableBooks,
    borrowedBooks: borrowedBooks,
    layout: false 
  });
  console.log(booksData);
});



app.post('/borrow', (req, res) => {
  const selectedBooks = req.body.books || []; // Array of selected book titles
  console.log(selectedBooks);
  
  // Update the availability property for selected books
  selectedBooks.forEach((selectedBook) => {
    const book = booksData.find((item) => item.title === selectedBook);
    console.log("book selected:")
    console.log(book);
    if (book) {
      console.log(book.available);
      book.available = false;
    }
  });
  
  fs.writeFile('books.json', JSON.stringify(booksData), 'utf8', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log('books.json updated successfully.');
    }
  });

  res.redirect('/home');
});

// Handle Return button click
app.post('/return', (req, res) => {
  const selectedBooks = req.body.books || []; // Array of selected book titles
  console.log(selectedBooks);
  // Update the availability property for selected books
  selectedBooks.forEach((selectedBook) => {
    const book = booksData.find((item) => item.title === selectedBook);
    console.log(book);
    console.log(book.available);
    if (book) {
      book.available = true;
    }
  });

  fs.writeFile('books.json', JSON.stringify(booksData), 'utf8', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log('books.json updated successfully.');
    }
  });

  res.redirect('/home');
});

app.listen(HTTP_PORT, onHttpStart);
```

```
[
    {
        "title": "The Shining",
        "author": "Stephen King",
        "available": true
    },
    {
        "title": "Rainbow Six",
        "author": "Tom Clancy",
        "available": false
    },
    {
        "title": "Steve Jobs",
        "author": "Walter Isaacson",
        "available": true
    },
    {
        "title": "Elon Musk",
        "author": "Ashley Vance",
        "available": false
    }
]
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what your specific challenge is.

Comment: I updated the code and the question, not sure if this is clearer